# Is it possible to make the sum of two random values a uniform distribution?

Tags: math, random, noise, perlin-noise

I'm trying to make Perlin Octaves to generate noise but to get the values, I have a grid of random values. Each grid square gets a random value [-0.5, 0.5] that adds together for potential height values [-1, 1].

The problem I ran into is that because I'm adding two random values, the resulting value isn't evenly distributed. Normally I wouldn't care, but because I'm adding multiple Octaves with different weights, the effects are amplifying and it's clustering around 0.

If I could make the sum of the values a uniform distribution though, it should help stop the clustering.

I tried just multiplying the resulting height value by a constant to make it closer to the range [-1, 1], but it's too unpredictable, and I want it to regularly return a value [-1, 1] on it's own without adjustment. I've also tried changing the weight function for the Octaves from (.5, .25, .125, .0625), but while other weights make it appear less clustered, that's also just because it's equivalent to multiplying by a constant.

Comment: @gordon Not true. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example? It is not clear how you add RVs

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux An example would be when you have 2 dice. When you have one dice, you know there's 1/6 probability of each number - uniformly distributed. When you add two dice though, there's 1/36 chance of a 2, 1/6 chance of a 7, and 1/36 chance of a 12. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem I think this might be central limit theorem

Comment: Dice are an example for discrete RVs, but I would like a distribution for a continuous RV that adds together to be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Of course, you're right @Severin Pappadeux, my bad.

Comment: Your question (whether a continuous uniform random variable can be the sum of two continuous random variables) might be more suited for [math.se].

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible.

Basically, you have convolution theorem which states that PDF of the sum of two variables is the convolution of the PDFs. See [here](https://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-sums.htm#:%7E:text=For%20any%20two%20random%20variables,sum%20of%20their%20expected%20values.&text=The%20proof%2C%20for%20both%20the,continuous%20cases%2C%20is%20rather%20straightforward.) at the bottom.

Which could be computed via Fourier transform. So PDF1 would have F[PDF1], then the same for F[PDF2], and result would be

F[PDF<sub>sum</sub>] = F[PDF1]*F[PDF2]

What I tried, I took Fourier transform of the uniform U01 RV (also known as characteristic function) and tried to take Sqrt of if and transform it back

Idea is if you multiply two of those Sqrts you'll get U01 Fourier image and transforming it back will give you U01 PDF. Like running this convolution idea back

Mathematica wasn't able to find Inverse Fourier Transform of the Sqrt of the Fourier U01 image, looks like it won't converge

UPDATE

Characteristic functions of several known distributions including U(0,1) are provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)).

I verified it with Mathematica. Then I took square root of it and tried to get back inverse Fourier transform image. Mathematica refused to do that, saying it won't converge.

Comment: if you can confirm that the function you had to integrate was exp(i*2*pi*s*x)*sqrt(sin(2*pi*s)/(2*pi*s)), then I didn't manage to find the result either and I have the feeling it converges but towards a complex function.

Comment: So @My Name, I think the only possible solution is to have two different PDFs, taking the square root is the only way to split something into the product of something else with itself but it's not the only way to split something into the product of two things.

Comment: That's true that there are infinite number of ways to split U01 Fourier PDF into product of two functions , but both of them to be Fourier image of some PDFs.

Comment: Concerning particular shape, I added some info how I did it